# Using TeamCity build templates how can I remove "Clean all files before build" from the template?

Tags: teamcity

I have a number of daily and in-response-to-svn-change builds that all derive from the same configuration template. I can set it so I can choose what branch to look at, what build steps to carry out and of course what triggers the build.

However I would like the daily builds to do a completely clean checkout, whereas the svn dependent ones (that obviously happen throughout the day) I am happy for them to simply to an update.

Simply un-setting the option in the template does not let me set them in each of the derived builds. Is there a build parameter that I can use to switch on clean builds for those builds that require it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you need one template for daily and one for nightly builds.

Comment: It seems a shame to duplicate all the rest of the build (which is shared) for just one bit!

Answer (score 3):

In each Project's "Version Control Settings", look under "Checkout setting". There are options to specify the checkout dir and also a checkbox to clean files before a build.

Comment: They are grayed out in each project due to them being set in the template. I cannot see how to remove them from the template to allow individual projects to have their own settings. apologies if I was not clear.

Comment: There's a way to declare variables in the template and substitute them with configuration parameters in each build project. Please refer more details at [link] http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2010/10/14/overriding-template-settings/

Comment: Since you are dealing with templates, you might also want to look at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-15182

Comment: @savinderpuri -1 None of this works - The OP is asking about a checkbox, and you can't parameterize a checkbox in the way you say

Answer (score 3):

There is an Additional Build Feature (Swabra) you can add that does a clean checkout if required.I have enabled this for our nightly builds but have not yet investigated the consequences.

See here for more detail on [Swabra](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Build+Files+Cleaner+%28Swabra%29)

Comment: For clarity, [in TC 6+, Swabra became built in functionality](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Swabra) (Although even the V8 docs doesn't make this tremendously clear)

Answer (score 2):

I so disliked the Accepted Answer that I put a conditional scorch into my built script.

Then I you can either set a default in the template and override in the one that needs the scorching or define it on an opt-out basis.

```
Get-ChildItem . -Include obj,bin -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
Remove-Item Artifacts -Recurse -Force
```

Why answer with such an unsightly hack? I'm hoping someone will chime in with a real solution and [then downvote this or preferably] comment.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to declare variables in the template and substitute them with configuration parameters in each build project. Please refer more details at [link] http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2010/10/14/overriding-template-settings/